# Access WMS server error message in Leaflet TileLayer.WMS

Tags: leaflet, wms, error, getmap

I am loading WMS maps using react-leaflet's [WMSTileLayer](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components/#wmstilelayer).

Depending on the layers loaded, the image appears or not.

When the image is not loaded, I have found that Leaflet returns a bunch of [tile error](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-wms-tileerror)'s:

[image: tile errors]

Unfortunately I can not find any helpful information in them.

When I send the GetMap query manually (https://wms.geo.admin.ch/?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=ch.vbs.armee-kriegsdenkmaeler,ch.swisstopo.hiks-dufour&styles&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=TRUE&version=1.3.0&greyscale=0&width=256&height=256&crs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=1017529.7205322665,5792092.255337515,1095801.2374962869,5870363.772301538) I get a much more helpful answer:

```xml
<ServiceExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.3.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.3.0/exceptions_1_3_0.xsd">
<script/>
<ServiceException> msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named 'ch.swisstopo.hiks-dufour'. msShapefileOpen(): Unable to access file. (/var/www/vhosts/wms-bgdi/private/wms-bgdi/ch.swisstopo.hiks-dufour.index) msShapefileOpen(): Unable to access file. (/var/local/geodata/ch.swisstopo.hiks-dufour.index) </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

So I can see that this is a server error because the server is missing a file. And I can also deduce what layer is the culprit.

How can I get this much more helpful error message from Leaflet?

So far I see only one workaround:

1. on tileerror, send a GetMap request using fetch
2. extract the helpful error from that answer

Comment: It seems you are out of luck here about getting some more info about tile load error. But as for your example of two WMS layers `ch.vbs.armee-kriegsdenkmaeler` and `ch.swisstopo.hiks-dufour`, it worked for me if I defined them as two separate Leaflet WMS layers.

Comment: @TomazicM yeah, you're right. My problem is more general but thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1):

You might try adding `EXCEPTIONS=INIMAGE&` to the GetMap request to get an image response rather than the default XML response.

> https://wms.geo.admin.ch/?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=ch.vbs.armee-kriegsdenkmaeler,ch.swisstopo.hiks-dufour&styles&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=TRUE&version=1.3.0&greyscale=0&width=256&height=256&crs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=1017529.7205322665,5792092.255337515,1095801.2374962869,5870363.772301538&EXCEPTIONS=INIMAGE&

Gives:

[image: INIMAGE error]

Comment: Yeah, that works with a separate getMap request. But not when using leaflet's TileLayer.WMS. How can I get a meaningful error when using leaflet's TileLayer.WMS?

Comment: To be more explicit: I can deal with an XML error (better than with an image). That is not the issue. The issue is to get a meaningful error when using leaflet's TileLayer.WMS.

Comment: My thinking was at least with an image response you will get the image showing in your application, it's no different from any other GetMap request, better than trying to handle a non image response and parsing it  etc.

Comment: How did you try to pass the value? as part of the url `https://wms.geo.admin.ch/?EXCEPTIONS=INIMAGE&` or as an option?

Comment: Actually, adding `EXCEPTIONS=INIMAGE` as parameters to TileLayer.WMS results in the error message being displayed instead of tiles, i.e. many times overlaying the map. That is unfortunately not a great user experience as it is unreadable

Comment: The error is tiled, it happens because there are no map tiles, not instead of map tiles.